# Selecting first value

Tags: sas

I have a dataset like this

```
ACC  two three ...
124  12  a
124  14  a
32   129 a
32   12  b
48   1   c
```

I would like to keep the first ACC, i.e. remove duplicates, based on column two.

I tried with

```
Data ...;
Set ... ;
By ACC two;
ACC=first.ACC;
keep ACC
two
three;
Run;
```

However I still have duplicates.
Can you tell me where I am wrong?

Desired output:

```
ACC  two three ...
    124  12  a
    32   12  b
    48   1   c
```

Comment: What do you mean by "based on column two"?

Comment: which is sorted by ACC and two. So I should select the account with the lowest value in col two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
data have;
input ACC two three $;
datalines;
124  12  a
124  14  a
32   129 a
32   12  b
48   1   c
;

proc sort data=have;
   by ACC two;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   by ACC two;
   if first.ACC;
run;
```